# addClass dont works on conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

I come to you with my next problem xd
This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

let imagesContainer = $(".slider__imageContainer");
let index = 0;

for(let item of imagesContainer) {
    if(item == imagesContainer[0]) {
        item.addClass("d-block");
    }
    else {
        imagesContainer.addClass("d-none")
    }
}
})
```

Why dont work the "addClass("d-block") function - but my "else" works fine.

and this is my HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider__imageContainer">
            <img src="images/cat-5852139_640.jpg" alt="" class="slider__imageContainer--image">
        </div>
        <div class="slider__imageContainer">
            <img src="images/kingfisher-6146356_640.jpg" alt="" class="slider__imageContainer--image">
        </div>
        <div class="slider__imageContainer">
            <img src="images/meerkats-6153748_640.jpg" alt="" class="slider__imageContainer--image">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not the element you are thinking, it refers to the `HTMLDocument` object. You can try

```
$(item).addClass("d-block");
```

Comment: When i set $(item) i get following error in my WebInspector:
addClass is not a function

Comment: @MarcoHadzija, better if you update the question with relevant HTML:)

Comment: I have Update my Code my HTML and also my JS Code

Comment: @MarcoHadzija, you should use the `addClass` on jQuery referenced object, please try `$(item).addClass("d-block");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use item instead of this. Also your code could be optimised further from:

```
 for (let item of imagesContainer) {
    if (item == imagesContainer[0]) {
      item.addClass("d-block");
    } else {
      imagesContainer.addClass("d-none")
    }
  }
```

to:

```
  imagesContainer.addClass("d-none");
  imagesContainer[0].addClass("d-block");
```